# Emacs indentation for switch...case statements

Tags: emacs, switch-statement, indentation

Indentation in Emacs always works, but I face some questions about `switch` - `case` statements.

For example,

```
switch (x) {
case 'A':
case 'B':
    printf("hello");

printf(...);
printf(...);
break;
}
```

I want it displayed in this way:

```
switch (x) {
case 'A':
case 'B':
    printf("hello");

    printf(...);
    printf(...);
    break;
}
```

How?

Comment: You should mention which mode you're using. Works for me in `c-mode`, `c++-mode`, `java-mode`, and `javascript-mode`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured this out:

Have the cursor over a `case` keyword. Then `C-c C-o`. Should then say something like `Syntactic symbol to change: case-label`. Hit `RET`. Then enter the default number of spaces you want the `case` label to be indented by.

Comment: But the case labels are already as required - the problem is with the statements after the blank line.

Comment: Oh, right. Whoops. Anyway, are case labels really supposed to have no indent like that?

Comment: Looks like the usual (GNU) style - all labels (including case labels) outdented 1 level.

Answer (score -1):

In a buffer:

```
`M-x c-set-style` RET `k&r` RET
```

In file `.emacs`:

```
(c-set-style "k&r")
```

Comment: also `M-x apropos` `c-style-alist` for other options. Or just tab to see a list of them in the `c-set-style` interactive command.

Comment: it didn't work. the following is my configuration:<pre><code>(defun c-like-style ()
  (c-set-style "K&R")
  (setq tab-width tabwidth)
  (setq c-basic-offset tabwidth)

  (hs-minor-mode 1)
  (local-set-key (kbd "RET") 'reindent-then-newline-and-indent) ; Use C-j
  (local-set-key (kbd "C-c . r") 'ecb-rebuild-methods-buffer)
  (local-set-key (kbd "C-c C-f") 'eassist-switch-h-cpp)
  (local-set-key [?\C-\)] 'semantic-ia-fast-jump))
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'c-like-style)
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'c-like-style)
(add-hook 'java-mode-hook 'c-like-style)
(add-hook 'jde-mode-hook 'c-like-style)

Comment: @user915203, that information should be included in the question, as well as anything else non-default (use `emacs -q` or even `emacs --no-site-init` to confirm that the problem is with your settings rather than with the site's installation).